# ASP.NET A problem with jQuery and a WebService's method

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I invoke a WebService method **asynchronously**.

While the method is not complete, I use that jQuery code to update my progress bar (get progress value from that WebService)

```
   var intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 1000);

   function updateProgress() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "myPage.aspx/GetProgress",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#result").text = msg.d;
                    var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
                    if (value < 100) {
                        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", msg.d);
                        $("#result").text(msg.d);
                    }
                    else {
                        clearInterval(intervalID);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The problem is, that the browser sends the requests (let's say 15 times) to get the progress value, but that requests are waiting while the asynchronous method is complete. Then, my server sends 15 times that value for the browser.

**Why requests are waiting to complete the asynchronous method ??**

Answer (score 1):

When you set [`async: true`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you're telling the requests to complete sequentially *and* lock the browser while doing so.  If you want the UI to update, then you need to set a timeout instead of an interval, so the UI has time to update between requests, but it would be better to turn `async` off altogether and use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) instead, here's what I mean:

```
function updateProgress() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myPage.aspx/GetProgress",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#result").text = msg.d;
            var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
            if (value < 100) {
                $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", msg.d);
                $("#result").text(msg.d);
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(updateProgress, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This lets the request complete, doesn't lock up the browser or UI thread, and kicks off the next request when the first finishes, with a 1000ms delay, just adjust if needed.  Otherwise say the user has 1200ms latency, currently you're queuing up requests that are overlapping...it's best *not* to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) in a repeated AJAX situation, since you don't know how long the request itself will take.

Comment: so what would You recomment instead setInterval() to check that progress ?

Comment: @Tony - What's not working? "It isn't working" isn't a very helpful description, be specific about what is/isn't working :)

Comment: OK, I have fileUplad control and button inside the UpdatePanel control. After select a file and click on that button the import starts, and I see the postback is being processed. While that the browser sends the requests for progress, and gets them after that postback

Comment: @Tony - A file upload can't be asynchronous though, it must be uploading through an iframe or other mechanism...XmlHttpRequest can't upload files (for hopefully obvious security reasons).  How is it actually sending the file?